# SimpleDateFormat parse incorrect return

Tags: java, android

formatter allways return January. But if you convert back it's all good.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = formatter.parse(changeDate);
Log.d("Tag", changeDate);    
Log.d("Tag", date.toString());
Log.d("Tag", formatter.format(date));
```

LOG:
    01-29-2017
    Sun Jan 29 00:01:00 GMT+03:00 2017
    01-29-2017

```
02-13-2017
Fri Jan 13 00:02:00 GMT+03:00 2017
02-13-2017

06-08-2017
Sun Jan 08 00:06:00 GMT+03:00 2017
06-08-2017
```

Comment: `MM`, **not** `mm`. You are parsing *minutes*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

As [documentation tells](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `m` stands for `Minute in hour`. Month is `M`